# Debugging Mule flows from FunctionalTestCase test

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, mule, mule-studio

I'm new to Mule ESB and am trying to figure out how I can debug mule flows when running them from a FunctionalTestCase test class.

Using the visual debugger in Mule Studio works fine when running as a Mule Application, but not when running in a Junit test.

Is there any way to debug a flow that is run from a test? As an example, is there any way to step through TestFlow1 in a test method of a FunctionalTestCase if configured as below?

```
<flow name="TestFlow1" doc:name="TestFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        doc:name="VM" path="testIn" />
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="payload == 'Foo'">
            <logger message="Got Foo!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="testOut0" doc:name="VM"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Got [#payload]!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="testOut1" doc:name="VM"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>

<flow name="TestFlow2" doc:name="TestFlow2">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="testOut0" doc:name="VM"/>
    <test:component />
</flow>

<flow name="TestFlow3" doc:name="TestFlow3">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="testOut1" doc:name="VM"/>
    <test:component />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [known issue](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-2641).

Please upvote the issue and watch it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It would be a very helpful feature and I hope it gets prioritized. Upvoted.